# How to color the cells of MUI Data Grid with a range of color?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

[The MUI examples](https://codesandbox.io/s/l1l5w3?file=/demo.tsx) only teach how to choose between a defined number of colors.
I would like to be able to choose among all the possible colors.

**Example:**
We have a cell value between 0 and 100. Each value could be converted to a color thanks to a given function. Then, the color is applied to the color.

How would you proceed please?

Comment: You have linked the second example from the [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/style/#styling-cells) for styling a cell, the first example shows how to achieve what you are asking: https://codesandbox.io/s/v7y479?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: @jaboc smith: I do not think this example cover my needs. In it, every class has to be defined with the colors. In the example, there are only 3 values. Between my value 0 and 100, there are an infinite possible values. I would like to apply the whole color range betweent 0 and 100. How would you do it ?

Comment: You are correct, I guess this is a limitation to the grid. You could use use the `renderCell` to wrap your value with a div or similar and style that as you need, you should be able to use this in combination with `cellClassName` to get the div to fill the whole cell.

Comment: I have not think about this, I think this is the solution, cheers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution from @jacob smith is working:

> Use the renderCell to wrap your value with a div or similar and style that as you need, you should be able to use this in combination with cellClassName to get the div to fill the whole cell.

You would need something similar to the following in the column definition:

```js
cellClassName: (params: GridCellParams<number>) => {
      return "super-app";
    },
    renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
      const color = getColor(params.value);

      return (
        <Box
          sx={{
            backgroundColor: color,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%"
          }}
        >
          {params.value}
        </Box>
      );
    }
```

[Here is a codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/color-range-for-mui-datagrid-cells-dn7cnf?file=/demo.tsx)